# How to identify quartiles

Tags: r

Which age are in the bottom 25% of Glucose and the top 25% of Glucose?

[image]

to identify the top 25% and bottom I do this

```
x<- quantile(db$Glucose,0.25)
print(x)
y<- quantile(db$Glucose,0.75)
print(y)
```

I am a beginner in R I try if statement but I can't extract the age relative to a specific condition of other columns

Comment: I use this data set  https://www.kaggle.com/mathchi/diabetes-data-set

Comment: Hi ريم القحطاني ! You can use [`dput()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) function to make a copy of the data and that would be useful for the people here give more accurate advice. What you need is to index the dataframe by the values you are interested in. something like `df[df$glucose < x, "Age"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is subset the data based on the quantile of glucose for age. Here I am going to use the mtcars data to demonstrate.

```
mtcars$hp[mtcars$mpg < quantile(mtcars$mpg,.25)]
```

In the code above I want to know what the `hp` is when `mpg` is in the lower 25%ile of the dataset. In this example hp would be replaced with age and mpg would be replaced with glucose.

You can also write it in two steps if it is easier to read:

```
x <- quantile(mtcars$mpg, .25)

mtcars$hp[mtcars$mpg < x]
```

Comment: yah thank you i do some thing like this

Answer (score 0):

```
x<- quantile(db$Glucose,0.25)
print(x)
y<- quantile(db$Glucose,0.75)
print(y)

new_data<- db[db$Glucose<x, ]
a<- new_data$Age
new_data<- db[db$Glucose>y, ]
b<- new_data$Age
c(a,b)`enter code here`
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing and why you believe it is the best approach to your original question?